# query sql convert text field dd/mm/yyyy to date field yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: mysql, date

I've imported a CSV file into mysql with dates in format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

I now need a query to convert it from text to date format `yyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the [STR_TO_DATE(str, format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) MySQL function.

Example switching out `my_date_col` for a converted one:

```
BEGIN;
 ALTER TABLE `date_test` 
  ADD COLUMN `my_date_col_converted` DATE;

 UPDATE `date_test` 
  SET `my_date_col_converted` = STR_TO_DATE(`my_date_col`, '%d/%c/%Y');

 ALTER TABLE `date_test` 
  DROP COLUMN `my_date_col`;

 ALTER TABLE `date_test` 
  CHANGE COLUMN `my_date_col_converted` `my_date_col` DATE;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers so we know that the question is closed ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in the following way to convert your text in to a `DATE`:

```
STR_TO_DATE( datefield , "%d/%m/%Y" )
```

If you need this `DATE` in a specific format, you can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).
This probably isn't necessary in your case, but here's an example for completeness:

```
DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( datefield , "%d/%m/%Y" ) , "%Y/%m/%d" )
```

So, you could do this over the whole table with a single `UPDATE` to replace the current data with the reformatted data (while keeping the datatype the same):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET originalDate = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(originalDate,"%d/%m/%Y" ),"%Y/%m/%d" );
```

Or, if you want to convert the datatype of the column `DATE` you could alter the table to create a new `DATE` formatted column, use the above update to fill that column, remove the original column, and then (optionally) rename the new column to the old name.

```
ALTER tableName
ADD modifiedDate DATE;

UPDATE tableName
SET modifiedDate = DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( originalDate ,"%d/%m/%Y" ) ,"%Y/%m/%d" );

ALTER tableName
DROP COLUMN originalDate; 

ALTER tableName
CHANGE COLUMN modifiedDate originalDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work but it doesn't:

```
BEGIN;
 ALTER TABLE `date_test` 
  ADD COLUMN `my_date_col_converted` DATE;
 UPDATE `date_test` 
  SET `my_date_col_converted` = STR_TO_DATE(`my_date_col`, '%d/%c/%Y');
 ALTER TABLE `date_test` 
  DROP COLUMN `my_date_col`;
 ALTER TABLE `date_test` 
  CHANGE COLUMN `my_date_col_converted` `my_date_col` DATE;
COMMIT;
```

Also this should work: Doesn't Work

```
UPDATE db_test SET anticipated_court_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(anticipated_court_date,"%d/%m/%Y" ),"%Y-%m-%d" );
```

Server version: 5.0.95-community-log MySQL Community Edition (GPL)

However this works:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('8/31/12', '%m/%d/%Y'); // WORKS
```

Using MySQL - I couldn't find any solution that worked reliably. Even the same exact date wasn't converted successfully.

```
The solution I've found is this:  PHP
$user_date = "8/31/12"; // WORKS
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($user_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

The above were helpful, but the following worked for me on Mysql.

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `newcolumn` DATE NOT NULL ;
UPDATE `tablename` SET `newcolumn`=STR_TO_DATE(`oldcolumn`, '%d/%c/%Y')
```

Now delete the oldcolumn (if you wish).