Why is my STR_TO_DATE function returning null values?
Beginner in SQL here. I would like to convert my 'Date' column from text to date so that I can do datetime functions on it.
When I performed the following query to convert, MySQL Workbench returned null values instead.
select STR_to_date(ï»¿Date, '%y-%m-%d %T') from newschema.eth_1h_rev2
My date values come in the 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii' format instead of the standard 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' MySQL format, which may be why it did not convert successfully. Are there any ways to replace the format to the standard datetime format, or is that not the right answer?
I also tried CAST, CONVERT with the same results.
Apologies if there is already a similar question elsewhere. Thanks!

this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143476/query-sql-convert-text-field-dd-mm-yyyy-to-date-field-yyyy-mm-dd

I see you have slashes in your input. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038589/how-to-insert-date-type-value-with-slashes-instead-of-dashes-in-mysql

Can you explain the reason for ï»¿ characters in ï»¿Date?

The Format argument you pass to STR_TO_DATE should match the format of your input string, so in your case for you should probably use STR_to_date(Date, '%d/%m/%Y %T')

One thing to do is verify the actual type of the column. Good database design will use a datetime column type, which stores these values in a binary format that isn't human readable at all. Conversion from strings to dates should be at insert/update time, rather then select. Storing date values in a text column is considered a broken schema design. Then the tooling (such as Workbench) will convert the binary values to your preferred format automatically for display while working with the data. So just because you see dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii, that doesn't mean it's what you actually have.

[continued] Note this is separate from SQL date literals, which absolutely do still need to be represented initially as strings and have a standard format, which may also vary somewhat depending on what SQL dialect you're using. But internally, things work MUCH better if you let the database represent dates in binary.

Thank you everyone for the extremely helpful answers! To respond to @BartMcEndree the ï»¿ characters were generated when I did some manipulation on pandas, and I have since updated the column name.
